# How do I create an icon as a shortcut on MacOS to run specific shell command?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I want to create an icon (just like an Application) on my Mac and after clicking it, the Terminal app will shows up and run the command `ssh -D8989 user@xxxx.com` or any other commands.

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: See duplicate question. Just create a new *Application* in Automator.app and let it execute the AppleScript as linked. Where it says `do script " "`, you can use `do script "ssh user@host"` etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
cat > myscript.command
#!/bin/bash
ssh -D8989 user@xxxx.com
^D
chmod a+x myscript.command
```

Explanation: You just need a text file containing your shell commands, preferably with a "shebang" line at the top telling your shell which shell you'd like it to use to execute the script. You need to mark it executable using `chmod`, and you need the filename to end in `.command` so Finder sees it as a double-clickable shell script to hand off to Terminal.app.